# Send mail in Play2.4 whenever Logger.Error("some error")

Tags: java, email, logging, playframework-2.0, logback

I want to send mail whenever the following statement
 `Logger.Error("some error")` 
is encountered. 
One way that I can do this is to use the email sending code at every place wherever I have used `logger.error`. However I think that there is something like the `SMTPAppender` of `logback` which sends email by itself whenever `logger.error` is called but I cannot find the appropriate documentation or tutorials for this. Any help? What config to write...what plugins if any to be included and how?

Edit1: Here is my logback.xml

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>
    <SSL>true</SSL>
    <username>myusername</username>
    <password>mypwd</password>
    <to>toEmail</to>
    <from>fromEmail</from>
    <subject>Linka ERROR: %logger</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO"/>

  <logger name="crawler" level="DEBUG">
    <!--<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />-->
  </logger>

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

The build.sbt is as:

```
name := """my-dnd"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4.5",
  "javax.activation" % "activation" % "1.1.1"

)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

I am not getting any errors also in the console but no mail is being sent. What am i missing? Please guide.

Comment: This is the one thing which i do not like about Stack Overflow. Why the down vote? As you can clearly see, i am anew user so why not take a minute out of your very very very busy schedule and tell me what was wrong with the question. it will help me posting better ones.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, now that i have added code also, would you be kind enough to explain the reason

Comment: Yup, your edited question make my answer obsolete. Anways, it's much better now, as you include what you tried so far and what's not working. You should also add the logback tag and probably remove the playframework tag. This is more logback problem. (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: @Roman thanks for the tips...I really appreciate it